# Random line thickness -OpenCv

Tags: c, opencv

I'm working on an OpenCV application-using C API. I'm trying to get my `cvLine` function to have random thickness so the first time it draws it will have a thickness of 3 and the second maybe 10. Right now it is uniform thickness everytime it draws. I've tried implementing `cvRandInt` but even through research I'm having trouble understanding how to use this function.

```
CvRNG rng;

int thickness=cvRandInt(&rng);


IplImage* imgScribble = NULL;

while(true )
    {  

         IplImage *frame=0; 
         frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);
          if( !frame ) break;


         if(imgScribble == NULL)
             {   


     imgScribble = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), 8, 3);

             }



// Holds the yellow thresholded image 

  IplImage* imgYellowThresh1 = GetThresholdedImage1(frame,1);
  double moment10 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments_yellow, 1, 0);
  double moment01 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments_yellow, 0, 1);
  double area = cvGetCentralMoment(moments_yellow, 0, 0);
  int lastX = posX;
  int lastY = posY;
  posX = moment10/area;
  posY = moment01/area;

                if(lastX>0 && lastY>0 && posX>0 && posY>0)

                  {  

             cvLine(imgScribble, cvPoint(posX, posY), cvPoint(lastX, lastY), cvScalar(10,255,255), thickness,CV_AA, 0);                 

                   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MAIN
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    int MaxThickness=10;
    CvRNG rng = cvRNG(0xffffffff);
    //  CvRNG rng(time(NULL));
    cvNamedWindow("img");
    IplImage* img=cvCreateImage( cvSize(800,600), 8, 3 );

    int MaxThikness=10;

    int k=0;
    while(k!=27)
    {
        int thickness=cvRandInt(&rng)%MaxThikness;
        //cout << thickness << endl;
        cvSet(img,cvScalar(255,0,0));
        cvLine(img,cvPoint(50,50),cvPoint(0,0),cvScalar(100,255,255),thickness);        
        cvShowImage("img",img);
        k=cvWaitKey(500);
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

And for your fragment (I can't test it as it's not complete).

```
CvRNG rng = cvRNG(0xffffffff);
int MaxThikness=10;
int thickness=0;
IplImage* imgScribble = NULL;
IplImage *frame = NULL;
IplImage* imgYellowThresh1=NULL; 
while(true )
    {        
         frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);
          if( !frame ) break;
         if(imgScribble == NULL)
             {   
     imgScribble = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), 8, 3);
             }

// Holds the yellow thresholded image 

  imgYellowThresh1 = GetThresholdedImage1(frame,1);
  double moment10 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments_yellow, 1, 0);
  double moment01 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments_yellow, 0, 1);
  double area = cvGetCentralMoment(moments_yellow, 0, 0);
  int lastX = posX;
  int lastY = posY;
  posX = moment10/area;
  posY = moment01/area;

  thickness=cvRandInt(&rng)%MaxThikness;
  if(lastX>0 && lastY>0 && posX>0 && posY>0)
                  {  
             cvLine(imgScribble, cvPoint(posX, posY), cvPoint(lastX, lastY), cvScalar(10,255,255), thickness,CV_AA, 0);                 
                   }
```

Comment: It seems like the line is only drawing the thickness at the maximum number

Comment: I have updated the code above, I have tested it and it work well.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. The random code works, but the colour tracking code that I'm using gets confused within this loop and no longer tracks colour. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the code frament which you trying combine with this code?

Comment: I have added code to my answer. I can't test this fragment because there are variables defined/used out of this fragment, but I think it should work. It will change thickness every cycle.